# Proof for E[X|X] = X

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-expectation

I saw from the lecture that
$$E[X|X]=X$$

where $X$ is a random variable.
But when I am trying to prove it formally, I cannot reach this conclusion.
$$E[X|X]=\int{xf_{x|x}(x) dx}=\int{xf_{x,x}(x)/f_x(x)dx}$$
$$=\int{xf_x(x)/f_x(x)dx}=\int{xdx}=x^2/2$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try rewriting as $E[X|X=x]$.  Then, in the integrals, you should only integrate over the range for which $X = x$, as we are conditioning upon that.  That should get you most of the way there.

Comment: What do you mean by integrating over the range for which $X=x$? is it integrating from negative infinity upto x? That still would not give me the correct answer. I am confused as I am not doing anything illegal upto $\int{xdx}$. I just don't know how to go from here to x due to my limiting knowledge.

Comment: A clearer notation would be $E[X|X=t]$, then integrate over the area where $X=t$ (a point in this case).

Comment: @Ahn's hint is clearer than mine (+1). Ignore mine and try to follow his.

Comment: Or the following that needs a little bit advanced probability! By definition of conditional expectation, we have: $E[X|X]=E[X|\sigma(X)]$, where $\sigma(X)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $X$. Now, since $X$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable, by properties of conditional expectation, we get $E[X|\sigma(X)]=X$.

Comment: @stat - this is clearly not helpful for this question - how does any of this reveal the error in the above steps.  "properties of conditional expectation" are exactly what the OP is asking about!

Comment: @probabilityislogic: lol don't read my comment then, as it is for the people who know advanced probability!

Comment: @Anh Is it that when $X=t$, t comes out of the integral, and that the integral integrates to one, therefore it's t?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formal definition of the conditional expectation $E(X|Y)$ is a random variable $Z$, which  is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable and for each $A\in \sigma(Y)$:  $EX1_A=EZ1_A$. Then $E[X|X]=X$ follows directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have no idea what $\sigma(Y)$ and $A\in\sigma(Y):EX1_A=EZ1_A$ mean. Where can I learn more about them?

Comment: I just sit down and try to formally prove all the steps and realized (to my own dismay) that it is indeed not simple like I thought. What @mpiktas is saying means:
- $\sigma(Y)$ is the $\sigma-algebra$ of Y, meaning the measurable space that Y lives in.
- $1_A$ is an indicator variable, which takes value 1 within $A$ and 0 outside of $A$.

The rest I frankly don't understand fully, and I won't risk giving you a frivolous comment again.

Comment: @Alby Take any probability theory book, for example [Billingsley's Probability and Measure](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Measure-Wiley-Series-Statistics/dp/1118122372/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1380527814&sr=8-1&keywords=billingsley+probability). I must warn however that this might be a bit technical. But you mentioned that you try to prove the statement *formally* and formal mathematical definition of conditional expectation is a bit complicated at first sight.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in your derivation - namely its missing a delta function for the "joint" pdf.  The conditional pdf is given by:

$$f_{X|X}(x|X)=\frac{f_{X,X}(x,X)}{f_{X}(X)}= \frac{f_{X}(X)}{f_{X}(X)}\delta(x-X)=\delta(x-X)$$

The reason for the delta function is that the "joint" pdf must be evaluated at the same value for both arguments to make sense.  Then the integral is given by

$$E[X|X]=\int x\delta(x-X)dx =X$$

Comment: This gives nice, and useful, intuition, but should not be misunderstood as being a formal proof. That said, an actual proof (as in @mpiktas's answer) utilizes machinery with which the OP is probably unfamiliar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask why the join pdf is equal to $f_x(X)\delta(x-X)$? and where can I learn more about it?